# How to create a mask of an image in NextJS 13 for AI Image modification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js

I am building a room interior design application with NextJS and Replicate, the generation is done, now if I want to create a selective edit by creating a mask of an image like this
[Replicate Mask Edit](https://replicate.com/stability-ai/stable-diffusion-inpainting/examples), how do I do it in NextJS 13? using client components. The user should be able to draw over the imnage with a brush like DALLE 2
[image]